# Windows Store App (Winjs) - Template Selector (Dual Template)

Tags: javascript, html, templates, selector, winjs

i need a Grouped Listview that has two types of templates, i've reached to this:

Employee.html:

```
            <div id="dualTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none;">
                <div class="dualText" data-win-control="MvvmJS.UI.TemplateSelector"
                    data-win-bind="winControl.model:self MvvmJS.Binding.wbind"
                    data-win-options="{ 
                    selector: {                                
                        type: MvvmJS.UI.TemplateSelector.PropertySelector,                                
                        property: 'DocumentTypeCode',                               
                        pattern: 'html/Employee/Employee.html#{0}',} 
                    }">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-templateid="Receipts" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                <div class="Receipts">
                    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: Filename"></h4>
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Year"></h6>
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Month"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-templateid="ADeclaration" class="dualText ADeclaration" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                <div class="ADeclaration">
                    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: Filename"></h4>
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Year"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="listviewDocs" class="win-listview"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                data-win-options="{                        
                    itemTemplate: dualTemplate,
                    groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerDocsListTemplate')
                }">
            </div>
```

The data is coming from a Web Service, but here is the data from the "ViewModel"

```
for (var ir = 0; ir < employeeData[0][0].employeeDocuments.length; ir++) {
                   var dataItem = employeeData[0][0].employeeDocuments[ir];
                   employeeDocumentsList.push({
                       EmployeeId: dataItem.EmployeeId,
                       ContentType: dataItem.ContentType,
                       Filename: dataItem.Filename,
                       Month: dataItem.Month,
                       Year: dataItem.Year,
                       PayrollCode: dataItem.PayrollCode,
                       PayrollPeriod: dataItem.PayrollPeriod,
                       DocumentTypeCode: dataItem.DocumentTypeCode
                   });
               }

var documentsGroupedItems = employeeDocumentsList.createGrouped(
        function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.DocumentTypeCode;
        },
        function (dataItem) {
            return { DocumentTypeCode: dataItem.DocumentTypeCode };
        },
        function (group1, group2) {
            return group1.charCodeAt(0) - group2.charCodeAt(0);
        }
    );

WinJS.Namespace.define("EmployeeDocumentData", {
        items: documentsGroupedItems,
        groups: documentsGroupedItems.groups
    });

var listviewDocs = element.querySelector("#listviewDocs").winControl;
           listviewDocs.selectionMode = WinJS.UI.SelectionMode.none;
           listviewDocs.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout({
               horizontal: true
           });
           listviewDocs.itemDataSource = EmployeeDocumentData.items.dataSource;
           listviewDocs.groupDataSource = EmployeeDocumentData.items.groups.dataSource;
```

The data source is the EmployeeDocumentData, wich was working with one general template.

Right now, this isn't working, it only appears the grouped data without the template definition like there wasn't any template.

OBS: I took na exemple from the internet and i don't know if i need to pick the MvvmJs from somewhere because the site didn't said anything about that.

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Ok, i found a way to change the template but now i'm stuck...
The innerText ins't binding, any help?

HTML:

```
<div id="Receipts" class="Receipts" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: Filename"></h4>
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Year"></h6>
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Month"></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="ADeclaration" class="dualText ADeclaration" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                    <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: Filename"></h4>
                    <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Year"></h6>
                </div>

                <!-- data-win-options="{itemDataSource: EmployeeRelativeData.EmployeeRelativeInfo.dataSource, automaticallyLoadPages:true, itemTemplate:smallListIconTextTemplate, loadingBehavior:'randomAccess', layout:{type:WinJS.UI.ListLayout}, selectionMode:'none', swipeBehavior:'none', tapBehavior:'none'}"> -->
                <div id="listviewDocs" class="win-listview"
                    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                    data-win-options="{                        
                        groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerDocsListTemplate')
                    }">
                </div>
```

JS:

```
itemTemplateDocs: WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing(function (itemPromise) {
        return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete, error) {
            return itemPromise.then(function (currentItem) {
                var item = currentItem.data.DocumentTypeCode;
                var template;

                // Base the template on the type of data
                if (item == "Receipts") {
                    template = document.getElementById("Receipts").winControl;
                }
                else {
                    template = document.getElementById("ADeclaration").winControl;
                }

                template.render(item).then(function (element) {
                    complete(element);

                    // allow for some additonal manipulation after the element is rendered 
                    // and binding is finished
                }, function (e) {
                    error(e);
                });
            });
        });
    }),

var listviewDocs = element.querySelector("#listviewDocs").winControl;
        listviewDocs.selectionMode = WinJS.UI.SelectionMode.none;
        listviewDocs.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout({
            horizontal: true
        });
        listviewDocs.itemDataSource = EmployeeDocumentData.items.dataSource;
        listviewDocs.groupDataSource = EmployeeDocumentData.items.groups.dataSource;
        listviewDocs.itemTemplate = this.itemTemplateDocs;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good to have one single div as child of the WinJS.Binding.Template. I remember reading so when I started winjs dev work. since then, I always follow the pattern when defining listview templates. example:

```
<div id="Receipts" class="Receipts" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
   <div class="receipt-item">
        <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: Filename"></h4>
        <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Year"></h6>
        <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: Month"></h6>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do you know it is innerText binding issue? do you see the listview items rendering but without content?